# How to Run the methods one after the other in cucumber

Tags: sonarqube

I am trying to implementing the Automate the SonarQube from Cucmber, below is code of feature file

Feature: Bring up the sonarqube instance  and scan the code from the SonarScanner
Scenario: Perform certain Actions on the sonarQube
Given Check the SOnarQube Instace is Up or Not
When Scan the the Code from the Sonar Scanner
Then List the project Names from SonarQube
Then List out the Bugs and Issues of the Project

In the step definition file on the Given block i am checking weather SonarQube is up or not based, if its not up running the Startsonar.bat file.. but here to bring SonarQube up need 2 to 3 mins time, but in the mean time, When and  then block is starting executing.. i need an assistance while running the Given block other block should in idle state for 2 to 3 mins once Given block completes When block should start.

Regards,
Nandan

Comment: I have tried this Given('Check the SOnarQube Instace is Up or Not', {timeout : 120 * 1000},  function () not useful

Comment: Nandan, you can edit your question and add more information which is better than writing in comment.